# Set python path in spacy project

Tags: python, spacy, spacy-3

I'm using a spacy project to train a model.  I've registered a custom language so I need to provide some python code on the command line.  Here is a snippet of my project.yml

```
commands:

  - name: train
    script:
      - python -m spacy train configs/config.cfg --code my_language.py
```

The issue I'm having is how to specify the path to `my_language.py`.  I don't want to have to copy this code to my training directory (it is a Python package and not just one file).

I tried updating my Python path in project.yml like this:

```
- export PYTHONPATH=... ; python -m spacy train configs/config.cfg --code my_language.py
```

but I get the error:

```
Can not execute command 'export PYTHONPATH=...
```

Any suggestions for how to do this?

Comment: in bash you can set variable and execute a script like this: `PYTHONPATH=... python ...`. The `PYTHONPATH` change will be applied to this line only

Comment: I tried that too and get a similar error.  It seems to be something different than simply executing a shell command.